Azure Container App Jobs: Accessing Azure Files fails with mount error(13): Permission denied
I am trying to write data to an Azure Files share from an Azure Container App Job.
What I have done:

I have created the share

I have added it to my Container App Environment under the tab Azure Files (Using storage account key1)

I have added the share to the Volumes section of my Container App Job

I have added the volume to the container.


Yet when I start the Container App Job it errors out with this message:
Container 'container' was terminated with exit code '' and reason 'VolumeMountFailure'. One or more errors occurred. (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
) (Shell command exited with non-zero status code. StatusCode = 32 | StdOut =  | StdErr = mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
)

Base image for container container is python:3.12-alpine3.19 (kernel 6.6). Can anybody see what I am doing wrong or is this simply not supported?





In my case the issue was that Azure Container Apps Environment can't connect to a Storage Account if Maximum Security is set up:
This does not work:

What worked was the following custom setup:
SMB protocol versions SMB3.1.1;
SMB channel encryption AES-128-GCM;AES-256-GCM;
Authentication mechanisms NTLMv2;
Kerberos ticket encryption -


Where are these settings? On the Storage Account?

it's on the file share itself, but you can reach it from the storage account: "your storage account"->data storage->file shares->"your file share"->Next to Security profile (under SMB protocol settings

To use Azure File Share as Volume in Container App job it needs to be added in Container Environment which you have done already.
When you add the File share as Volumes in Container App Jobs in Volume Mounts section you need to select the volume name from the list which are available in Container Environment.
In Mount Path you need to mention the path you using to save the data, OR the path required as per you image.
In my situation path is /mnt/azurefileshare.
Below worked is give simple code which worked for me.
entrypoint.sh:
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT_FILE="/mnt/azurefileshare/output.txt"

echo "Hello from Azure Container App!" > $OUTPUT_FILE

cat $OUTPUT_FILE

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]

OUTPUT:








Thank you for your answer. In my case the solution was that Azure Container Environment can't use the max security settings of file storage. I'll elaborate in another answer.
